# Recv failure when I use docker-compose for set up redisDB

Tags: redis, docker-compose

sorry but I'm new to redis and dockers and I'm getting stuck.

I want to connect redis to my localhost with docker-compose. When I use docker-compose my web and my redis shows that they are ON but when i try to make curl -L http://localhost:8081/ping for test it I get this message "curl: (56) Recv failure:"

I tryed to change my docker-compose.yaml but is not working

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:6379"
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ""
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

My expected results are this:

curl -L http://localhost:8081/ping

pong

curl -L  http://localhost:8081/redis-status

{"redis_connectivity": "OK"}

Comment: Step 1: Check your `docker logs`.

Comment: This has both Redis, which may be working fine, and some Python app, which could be busted or erroring out. Narrow down the problem to one of these two containers.

Comment: @tadman Everything is correct in the logs, just when I try to access i find this issue, the web and the redis are working properly

Comment: What port is your Python app supposed to be listening on? You're forwarding 8081 -> 6379 which looks wrong.

Comment: @tadman I want to forward to the web the redis, so I thought I had to redirect redis to the port where I want to make the requests

Comment: try to run just the web app without connectivity to redis. Then try to connect to ping endpoint.

Comment: @rok I have the same problem doing this, web is started but can't reach ping endpoint

Comment: The app should connect to Redis on its own. You're asking Docker to connect to port 6379 on that Python container, and there's no service running there so you get nothing. Try `8081:8081`.

Comment: Thank you @tadman will try it tomorrow, here is late night. But one think I don't understand is if I do this then how I will connect the web with the redis? I should give some port with redis for connect no?

Comment: You can't get Docker to do that for you, the Python code must make a Redis connection independently.

Comment: Thank you @tadman now I can acces to the ping functionality, now I only have to connect the redisdb for show the state. You helped me a lot, thank you.